# Can I disable all Prettier format rules and use just a specific plugin? (Prettier)

Tags: prettier

I know it's possible to ignore files and specific segments of code, but with the recent launch of Tailwind CSS Prettier plugin, is it possible to disable all format rules and use just the plugin for automatic class sorting?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I haven't been able to find a method to turn off default Prettier formatting.

If you use Visual Studio Code then you could use Ryan Heybourn's [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=heybourn.headwind).

If you use a JetBrains IDE then you could use Jayson Lindsley's [plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/13376-tailwind-formatter).

If you use the command line then you could use Praveen Perera's [CLI](https://github.com/avencera/rustywind).